# CFchart : 2 Y-axes with only one of them reversed

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfchart

I'm trying to plot my chart having 2 y-axes. I want one of them to be reversed. 
The chart signifies the "page rank" and "number of hits" vs the "Date Range". 
I want the Rank to be in reverse order (1 at the top and Max_Rank on the x-axis). 
I tried changing the graph style xml

```
<yAxis isReversed = "true">
```

and

```
<yAxis2 isReversed = "false">
```

but the chart is plotted based on `<yAxis>` order only. How should I modify the xml?

Edit 1 (for Clarity) : I had generated the XML with the Webcharts Util tool but it didn't work. As part of troubleshooting the issue, I tried manipulating the XML manually like `<yAxis2 isReversed = "false">` but still no luck. Hence, reaching out for any other way for achieving the same.

Comment: Your second example is not valid XML. ColdFusion 9 ships with a chart designer (WEB-INF/cfusion/charting/webcharts3d.bat): can you not use that to design your chart & generate your XML?

Comment: @AdamCameron : Yes, the 2nd line `<yAxis2 isReversed = "false">` is not the correct way but that's what I tried since `<yAxis2>` was reversing if `<yAxis isReversed = "true">`.

Comment: To add, I had generated xml using Webcharts tool.

Comment: So - to be clear - you generated the XML with the charting util and *that didn't work*? This is fairly significant information to omit from your question, isn't it? Can you please update your question to provide all relevant information about how you addressed the problem, and what troubleshooting you've done. Don't make us guess. There is no limit on how much useful/relevant information you can put in the question.